# Does the sequence contain a prime for the start values $97$ and/or $184\ $?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

Consider the sequence $$n_1=a$$ $$n_{k+1}=(k+1)n_k+1$$ for $k\ge 1$

The positive integer $a$ is the starting value. If we have $a=77$, the first prime in the sequence is $n_{210}$ with $400$ digits. I checked the values from $1$ to $200$, but I did not find a prime yet for the starting values $a=97$ and $a=184$.

> Does the sequence contain a prime for $a=97$ and/or $a=184$ ? Of course, $k=1$ is ruled out, otherwise $a=97$ would give a prime immediately. If such a prime with either start value exists, it must have more than $3\ 000$ digits.

Comment: No primes through the first 1000 terms of the sequence starting at $97$ by my count.

Comment: Maple indicates that $n_{2316}$ is a prime for $a=97$, with $6791$ digits.

Comment: @Sil   PARI/GP approves this number to be a (very probable) prime. For $a=184$, I passed $6\ 000$ digits and index $2\ 100$

Comment: I restarted $a=184$ , but this time with trial division , should be much faster now :)

Comment: I passed $10\ 000$ digits and index $3\ 200$ for $a=184$

Comment: Is this math, or the Perils of Pauline?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Perils_of_Pauline_(1914_serial)

Comment: Well gone up to $9518$ index for $a=184$ ($33739$ digits), but no prime...

Comment: @Sil Thank you for the search! Is your program stil running, or did you stop it ?

Comment: It ran whole day and found no prime up to index $11966$ and $43605$ digits, the primality test takes quite a long time at that point.

Comment: No result for $a=184$ up to $k=20000$ (still running).

Comment: @pietfermat Thanks for the verification! So you soon arrive at $80\ 000$ digits (Or maybe you have passed it already)!

Comment: Yes, $k$ has passed $21000$ and $n_k$ has more than $82000$ digits.

Comment: @pietfermat Wow! Really impressing!